# Size of prime factors of $\text{gcd}(n,\phi (n))$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

At [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34748/is-the-probability-that-n-and-phin-totient-function-are-coprime-one-for-rand/94251#94251) MathOverflow post there is an interesting comment below the O.P.'s question. The comment is due to [Greg Martin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/5091/greg-martin) and it basically reads that

*Allmost all integers have the property that $\text{gcd}(n,\phi (n))$ is equal to the product of all prime powers dividing $n$, which are also less than $\log \log n.$*

**Question:** I was thinking about it, but how can we get this $\log\log n$ bound? Do you have any hints or references for the proof? I believe that very elementary techniques don't work.

**Motivation:** If I will understand how this result is derived, I will also realize how we can intuitively guess that (using arguments of probabilistic nature)

$$\#\{n\leq x,\ \text{gcd}(n,\phi (n))=1 \}\sim x\prod_{p\leq \log \log x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right),\ x\rightarrow +\infty,\ \ \ (1)$$

where $n$ stands for a positive integer and $p$ denotes a prime number. Using Merten's theorem, $(1)$ then becomes what Erdos proved [here](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1948-11.pdf).

Comment: Indeed, this seems somewhat counter-intuitive. One readily finds that this implies that the probability that for "random" $n$ we have $v_p(n)<\log \log n$ for all $p$ is zero, whereas the probability that for "random" $n$ we have $v_p(n)<1+\log \log n$ for all $p$ is one.